# Ormlite foreign collection save and fetch data

Tags: android, collections, ormlite

Im a entry level developer im using ormlite  for database can any body help me how to store array of data in database using ormlite using ormlite and to fetch that data

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please flesh out your question so far.  What docs have you read?  What have you tried?  What code have you written that isn't working?